# Is it more advantageous to learn the writing system or the spoken form of a language first?

Tags: reference-request, writing-system, speaking, writing

There are several primary aspects of a language, including both the writing system and the spoken form of a language. What does scientific research say about the order to learn these two factors when learning a language with an unfamiliar alphabet?

By *more advantageous*, I'm asking which order will yield the greatest level of fluency in the least amount of time.

Comment: But… this can be the opposite for different students. Someone better "accepts" the classic school-like approach, others would prefer the "Pimsleur's" style (speaking/comprehending way ahead of reading/writing). Are you asking about teaching a large group of people, where some statistics can apply?

Comment: @bytebuster (and fi12) What people like most does not always match what works best! So studies would be useful. The question has been addressed for Japanese and Chinese in [Is it necessary to learn the characters of a language that uses logograms?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/a/2166/800) and [First learn speaking and then writing OR both at once?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/a/2529/800), though without references to studies.